# Modify page_load method for radiobuttonlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I have a page with radio buttons and a textarea that populates data dynamically based on your selection. The radio buttons act as a list of article titles and on selection you see the content of the article.

Within my pageload method, I want to allow users to be able to see a URL in their browser that points to value they've. That way they can link to the article within another source.

Currently, the method I have allows me to link to the button selection if I manually type in the following example URLs:

```
http://localhost/test/Articles_test.aspx?selected=1
http://localhost/test/Articles_test.aspx?selected=2
```

I'd like to modify this so that the URL appears in the browser when a radio button selection is made. Plus, on page load defaults to the "0" index if no value parameter was specified.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        int selected;

        if (int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["selected"], out selected))
            RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = selected;
            RadioButtonList1.DataBind();         
    }
}



protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        string strRedirect;
        strRedirect = "frm_Articles.aspx?selected=" + RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex;
        Response.Redirect(strRedirect);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your radiobutton list to post back on change.  Then, in the handler, do a redirect to the appropriate URL:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    int selected;

    if (int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["selected"], out selected))
        RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = selected;
        RadioButtonList1.DataBind();         
}
protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string strRedirect;
    strRedirect = "frm_Articles.aspx?selected=" + RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex;
    Response.Redirect(strRedirect);
}
```

Comment: i added this handler which seems to work but the data is not binding on page load. so i don't see the radio list or textarea data unless i hit f5 `protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { string strRedirect; strRedirect = "frm_Articles.aspx?selected=" + RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex; Response.Redirect(strRedirect); }`

Comment: @MG:  Change the binding to re-bind every time, not just the first time.  You can probably also disable viewstate in this case.

Comment: how do i set it to rebind everytime?

Comment: when i implement your code. my first selection works, it show the correct data in the textarea and produces a correct url in the browswer http://test.com/test.aspx?selected=2. then we i click on other radio buttons, it defaults back to my first selection and holds that url in the browser.  i also can not cut and past a link to that selection in a new broswer to see the results (i just get a blank page)

Comment: That sounds like the databinding is not working properly.  Try explicity setting the values, then calling databind.